# MVVMCross iOS Supported Orientations

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross, autorotate

With the update of iOS(Monotouch) to 6, the method of choosing whether or not to rotate is no longer dependent solely on the ViewController.
With GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations and ShouldAutorotate being the method of doing so now, it is necessary to control the RootViewController. Otherwise the local override methods value will just be ignored.
Doing this in Objective C or even is straight Monotouch is pretty straight forward, but MVVMCross seems to handle most of the Pushing and Popping of the ViewControllers in the background, I am unable to get these methods to work with MVVMCross.

Is there some way of controlling orientation properly with MVVMCross and iOS6 or is it just not supported yet?

Answer (score 1):

MvvmCross pushes and pops the viewcontrollers via a component called the presenter. This is what provides the RootController and helps it interact with its children.

It's easy to customise and override the presenter in the App Setup.cs process - you can implement and return your custom presenter in `protected override IMvxTouchViewPresenter CreatePresenter()`.

For some examples on this, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html

Comment: So the default mvx iOS presenter doesn't support rotation. That seems strange.

Comment: The default presenter does support rotation - it presents a default UINavigationController - which by default fully supports rotation. You are free to consider Apple's and Mvx's default behavior "strange" - fortunately it is very easy to customise the default behavior with your own preferred interpretation of normality.

Comment: The only mvx samples for iOS I have seen all support iOS 5 form of rotation which has since been deprecated. The newer methods as of 6 are all dependent on the ViewController stack in order to push up orientation masks. The default behavior of the presenter either doesn't account for this or is somehow being blocked. Have you attempted to make new apps that target iOS 6?